# fetchRow does not returns a proper array

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to fetch a row from database but when it returns something like this below rather than a proper array.

```
Zend_Db_Table_Row Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [firstname] => Tuhin
        [lastname] => Biswas
        [email] => tuhin@gmail.com
    )

[_cleanData:protected] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [firstname] => Tuhin
        [lastname] => Biswas
        [email] => tuhin@gmail.com
    )

[_modifiedFields:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_table:protected] => Application_Model_DbTable_Client Object
    (
        [_name:protected] => client
        [_definition:protected] => 
        [_definitionConfigName:protected] => 
        [_db:protected] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object
            (
                [_pdoType:protected] => mysql
                [_numericDataTypes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 1
                        [2] => 2
                        [INT] => 0
                        [INTEGER] => 0
                        [MEDIUMINT] => 0
                        [SMALLINT] => 0
                        [TINYINT] => 0
                        [BIGINT] => 1
                        [SERIAL] => 1
                        [DEC] => 2
                        [DECIMAL] => 2
                        [DOUBLE] => 2
                        [DOUBLE PRECISION] => 2
                        [FIXED] => 2
                        [FLOAT] => 2
                    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it wont return array automatically,
if you want then you can use following in the model

```
public function getRow($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }
```

or directly from controller

by calling toArray() after the fetchrow,

like `$result=$model->fetchRow($where)->toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Zend library, it's not supposed to return an array. See the docs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.read

From the above if you want the row as an array use:

```
$row->toArray();
```